# vs2015 - Javascript/WinJS. Error with .winControl (undefined or null reference)

Tags: javascript, winjs, visual-studio-2015

I'm learning (trying) JavaScript/WinJS with new VS2015 RC. I created an UAP Project and I want to bind templates.

I have seen few tutorials and examples but when try myself I get that error with the render property.

Here are code implied (JavaScript):

```
    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("default.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {
            var templateControl = element.querySelector("#templateControl");

            var obj = { propOne: "Text text text", propTwo: 2 };
            //fails here
            templateControl.winControl.render(obj, 
                element.querySelector("#renderHere"));
        }
    });
```

code (HTML):

```
<div id="renderHere"></div>
    <!--Template-->
<div id="templateControl" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <p data-win-bind="innerText:propOne"></p>
    <p data-win-bind="innerText:propTwo"></p>
</div>
```

I have a 'click' event on 'templateControl' and works fine, however, as I said, winControl throw me undefined or null. I'm pretty sure it's me, but it's all at preview so there it's the doubt.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using ```getElementById``` instead of ```querySelector```? I don't know winjs so it's just a wild guess. Or should they be queried using the winjs query function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229847.aspx

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I didn't want to make a loong post, but, I tried that, tried getting winControl into a var and then render. renderHere into a var and after render it... and something else but I don't even rembember. Mmm... I saw codeShow, and try.buildwinjs.com binding templates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use WinJS Template to bind data with HTML, you can do it this way:

```
<div id="someId">
    <p data-win-bind="innerText: propOne"></p>
    <p data-win-bind="innerText: propTwo"></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("default.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        var obj = { propOne: "Text text text", propTwo: 2 };
        WinJS.Binding.processAll(element.querySelector("#someId"), obj);
    }
});
```

Also, `winControl` property is set when `WinJS.UI.processAll()` is done, until then it's undefined.

WinJS Templates are best suited for use with different controls such as List, Repeater etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at the end I did it that way. I'm not able to make it works with templates, even with `processAll().done(// code)`, having the same issue.